# Could someone help identify this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Uploading pictures of a bike...I think it's a schwinn...don't know anything about it....the bike has a red plastic seat with holes that is not on right now...If someone could help identify these, it would be much appreciated. Thanks[image]

Comment: From this picture the details of frame construction cannot be determined. A closer, clearer picture of the frame is needed to increase the chances of identifying the maker.

Comment: The only distinctive thing I can see is the area of chain stays just aft of the BB, and how they come together.   It only has one brake, front on left hand which is indicative of the US Kids market.

Comment: @DavidD - Will get a better picture. Thanks for letting me know!